# CSS - positioning divs from left to right

Tags: css, layout, html, positioning

I want the black and white squares that share a tile/cell to overlap. The tile/cell blocks (There will be more, ideally) should fill the container of arbitrary size from left to right before going to the next row. What am I doing wrong? I thought left to right was default, but I know I am overriding some defaults with absolute positions.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hc7af/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.cell{
    ...
    float: left;
}
```

Is this what you mean?

Also if you change the p element to a div it will fix the no-wrapping issue. I suspect it has to do with default styles.

Comment: It's closer. The black and white squares should overlap exactly.

Comment: See my edit for wrapping. I think the issue with overlapping might also have to do with default padding and other defaults.